# Unable to change default program to open a file from cmd

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line, cmd.exe

Once I thought, what can happen if I open the CPP file with cmd. I thought it will work similar to the `type` command in cmd, but when I understand it isn't, I wanted to change the default program from cmd. But I'm unable to change this. I searched in Google and I tried three different ways to change the program but I'm unable to change it. Here are my three ways :-

1.I right-click the file and then chose `Open with -> choose default program` the `always use the selected program to open this file` is not selected.

2. I right-click the file and then chose `properties` and I saw there is no change button.
3. I went to `Default programs -> associate a file type or protocol with a program` then I chose .cpp extenstion and when I clicked change button the `always use the selected program to open this file` was not selected.

Now, can someone tell me a way to change this program from the default program? Because when I want to open this .cpp file it always opens with cmd and I don't want to open this program with cmd. And I don't want to go to `Open with -> Notepad`every time I want to open this file with notepad.

Comment: see `assoc /?` and `ftype /?`. To see how it works for `*.txt` files, see `assoc .txt` and `ftype txtfile`

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to say. BTW I can change the default program to open another file extension such as .cc, .cxx, .cp, etc. But their default program is not set to cmd. I only chose cmd to open the .cpp file and now I can't change the default program.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `assoc` and `ftype` as suggested by @Stephan. Run CMD.EXE (as Administrator). This should set up new relationship between file extension and a new filetype (Notepad or notepad++):

```
ASSOC .cpp=MyCPP
ftype MyCPP="%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE" "%1"

ftype MyCPP="C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"
```

Just typing `ftype` will print a long list, it may be that there is already a suitable ftype name to use in assoc such as this one:

```
ASSOC .cpp=txtfile
```

Comment: ASSOC .cpp=MyCPP is not working. Here is what cmd saying: `C:\Users\User>ASSOC .cpp=MyCPP
Access is denied.
Error occurred while processing: .cpp.`.

Comment: Are you running CMD.EXE as Administrator?

Comment: No, I just run it by double-clicking from the start menu. However, I found my solution in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543254/how-to-enable-always-use-the-selected-program-to-open-this-kind-of-file-option). Thank you!

Comment: And even when I run it as Administrator, it still failed.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can do this by using **`Reg Add`** too...

```powershell
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%i in (C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe,C:\Windows\notepad.exe
  )do if exist "%%~i" set "_path_notepad=%%~i" && goto :regadd 

:regadd
2>nul (

"%__APPDIR__%reg.exe" add "HKCU\Software\Classes\.cpp" /ve /d "cppfile" /f
"%__APPDIR__%reg.exe" add "HKCU\Software\Classes\cppfile" /ve /d "C++ Code File" /f
"%__APPDIR__%reg.exe" add "HKCU\Software\Classes\cppfile\shell\open\command" /ve /d "\"!_path_notepad:\=\\!\" \"%%v\"" /f

) >nul && endlocal || (endlocal && echo/Something is very wrong here^!!) & %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1
```

**Obs.: 1** You may need to run this bat with Administrator credential, run it as an administrator

**Obs.: 2** This is an adaptation of another answer, that the author **[it wasn't me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60964830/8177207)**